# Access Query is forever executing

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to optimize a legacy application which uses Access as database. The issue with some of the queries are that, they are not returning anything after running hours. I am trying to figure out the issue by adding joins one by one. Now I got struck with one of the query as it is not returning anything and executing forever..
The query is behaving like this after adding Left Join which is using SubQueries to get the data.
Any suggestions would be heartily appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining on an aggregated column (`MaxOfColumn`) probably doesn't work well.

I suggest: insert the result of `[qry Aggregate Query]` into a temp table. Join that table instead in your problematic query.

You can use a SELECT INTO query for that (and delete the old temp table beforehand), or an INSERT INTO query (and empty the temp table beforehand).

**Edit**
Once you have it working in principle, I suggest using an Append query (INSERT INTO) instead of a Make Table query.

So your temp table stays in place, and you can add indexes on the fields you use for JOINs, to further improve performance.

To open the main query, you then do in VBA:

```vb
' Empty temp table
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Temptable"
' Run Append query
CurrentDb.Execute "NameOfYourAppendQuery"
' Open main query
DoCmd.OpenQuery "MainQuery"
```

Comment: @Lara: Do some reading, try it out. It is not so hard. Query types: http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/queries/#Action_Queries . Make a copy of `[qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]`, change it into a **Make Table** query. Run it. Use the resulting table in your main query instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link Andre.I created and run Make Table.Now in the query Shall I do joins like `LEFT JOIN [MakeTableName]
ON [tbl ADW].H10_STAFF_PARTY_ID = [MakeTableName].STF_STAFF_PARTY_ID)`. Is it the right way ?

Comment: @Lara: yes, wherever you currently have `[qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]`, replace it with `[MakeTableName]`.

Comment: It seems like working at first sight, after updating sub queries to temp tables.I will Validate and accept this as answer.

Comment: Just one more thing wanted to clarify, Will using Make Table will give old data or it will fetch the latest one as being done by the original query ?

Comment: Every time you run the Make Table or Append query, it will give the current data. But you must make sure that this happens always before opening the main query, or it will use the old data from the temp table. This is avoided by using the code above to open the main query.

Comment: One last dout !, I am having confusion between these two terms i.e. `Temptable` and `NameOfYourAppendQuery`. Wont the name of both will be same and that is `MakeTable Name` ? Please explain this ..Thnks

Comment: `TempTable` = `MakeTable Name`. `NameOfYourAppendQuery` is the copy of `[qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]` that you changed into an Append query (that inserts into TempTable).

Comment: Okay. Do I need to execute by the name only like `Currentdb.execute "qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE"` or the query inside `[qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]` ?

Comment: Only the append query name, as in my code example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding indexes on the tables on these columns :

```
[tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF] - (STF_END_EFF_DT)
[qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE] - (maxOfSTF_END_EFF_DT)
```

Although it seems like you are not even using this column, you already have it available on `maxOfSTF_END_EFF_DT` , so why join to this table??

Comment: I am joining to get `STF_END_EFF_DT` Column.`STF_END_EFF_DT` is already an Index and `qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE` is Subquery ..Any thing that I am missing here ?

Comment: But isn't `STF_END_EFF_DT` = `maxOfSTF_END_EFF_DT` ? You already have this info.